# window can't addsubview with swift

Tags: swift, window, appdelegate, addsubview

In function Appdelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions implement :

```
var testView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.window?.addSubview(testView)
self.window?.bringSubviewToFront(testView)
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But not show testView.

Comment: refer this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ibVlOx2o7I

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is give frame to your window.

and your code will be:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

var testView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0 , 0, 100, 100))
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.window?.addSubview(testView)
self.window?.bringSubviewToFront(testView)
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: TestView show ok, but screen is black color, i need to bring testView in font of navigation controller. (testView is footer bottom). tks!

Comment: You question was how to show test view. you doesn't mentioned anything else.accept the answer if this works..:)